# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Son'

Tags: python, pandas, string, floating-point, data-conversion

I am getting the error-

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Son'
> My dataset

[image]

My code -

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Survey Result - Sheet1 (1).csv')
feature_cols = ['Gender','Age']
X = data.iloc[:,[0,1]].values
y = data.iloc[:,2].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.25, random_state= 0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)
```

How do I convert string into float here?

Comment: Here you're applying `standardization` to you data, your data should be numbers only. please there is no numeric column, so you can't standardize them.

Comment: In this case, the problem is that you are trying to convert the column 'Gender' that is not a numeric value, it is not possible.

Comment: you try to do `float("Son")` - what float result  do you expect?

Comment: you will have the same problem with `float("0-18")` - what (single) float result do you expect?